# tailwind is not working with javascript and vite

Tags: tailwind-css, vite

I'm building a javascript app with vite.
I want to use tailwind for quick styling but setting it up in my project is something I struggle with all the time.

From the experience I've set it up but it's not working and I don't know why..

I suspect it is because of my change of root directory in the vite project.

My homepage:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
<link href="/src/style/output.css" rel="stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Hermes</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>My homepage</h1>
 <a href="test.html">Test</a>
 <div id="app" class="h-14 bg-gradient-to-r from-purple-500 to-pink-500">h</div>
 <script type="module" src="../main.ts"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My tailwind config:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
 content: ["./src/views/*.html"],
theme: {
extend: {},
},
 plugins: [],
}
```

My main.css (input file by tailwind)

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

**The output file which is linked in the html, is full of the basic style rest by taildwind**

This is my folder structure:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to create the `postcss.config.cjs` file manually with this content:

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
};
```

The [tailwind docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite) make it sound as though `npx tailwindcss init -p` will automatically create `postcss.config.cjs` but that didn't happen for me.

> Install tailwindcss and its peer dependencies via npm, and then run the init command to generate both tailwind.config.cjs and postcss.config.cjs.

Once I added `postcss.config.cjs` and restarted the dev server the styles were applied.